# In Browser Javascript Editor and Execution

Tags: javascript

I am developing an Enyo web application and would like to allow users to write their Javascript code in the browser and execute it.

I can do this by using `window.eval`.  However, I have read about the evils of eval.

Is there anyone that could shed some light on how examples like http://learn.knockoutjs.com/, http://jsfiddle.net, etc do in browser execution safely and what the best practices are?

Comment: http://jsbin.com is open source, and [hosted on github](https://github.com/remy/jsbin). Makes it very easy to study its code.

Comment: Just have the code executed on a different domain and you're pretty much done.

Comment: What have you read about the evils of eval?

Comment: @Pumbaa80 , heres one example - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx

Comment: @JonathanSampson thanks, that is a lot of help.

Comment: @Yoshi, what do you mean by executing it on a different domain?  It'll be executed on the client

Comment: @Yoshi, what exactly does putting the iframe in a separate domain accomplish? one thing i can think of is that if host site has cookies, the script on the other domain wouldn't be able to read those cookies. is that the only thing it accomplishes? are there other issues to consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eval is considered evil for all but one specific case, which is your case of generating programs during runtime (or metaprogramming). The only alternative would be to write your parser/interpreter (which can be done relatively easily in javascript, but rather for a simpler language than javascript itself - I did it and it was fun). Thus using `eval()` function here is legitimate (for making a browser-side compiler to a reasonably fast code, you need to use eval for generated compiled javascript anyway).

However, problem with eval is security, because evaluated code has the same privileges and access to its environment as your script that runs it. This is a topic quite hot recently and EcmaScript 5 was designed to partially address this issue by introducing strict mode, because the strict-mode code can be statically analyzed for dangerous operations.

This is usually not enough (or problematic for backward compatibility reasons), so there are approaches like [Caja](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caja_project) that solves security by analyzing the code on a server and allows only strict safe subset of javascript be used.

Another often used approach is protect the user, but not protecting from malicious attacks using running the user generated javascript in an `<iframe>` element embedded in the parent page (usually used by sites like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)). But it is not secure for the `iframe` can access its parent page and get to its content.

Even in this `iframe` approach there has been some progress recently e.g. in chrome to make it less vulnerable by using [`sandbox`](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_iframe_sandbox.asp) attribute

```
<iframe src="sandboxedpage.html" sandbox="allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

where you can even specify different privileges.

Hopefully, we will have an easy way to use safe and easy metaprogramming soon, but we are not there yet.

Comment: Great answer - I've been looking into the sandboxed iframes and use strict mode.  Thanks for posting an answer.